# How to create an OK/Submit button in the ActionBar?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, contextual-action-bar

I actually have two questions:

1. Is there a way to mark a menu item in the ActionBar as the OK/submission button, or is it just a regular item?
2. Is there a built-in theme for an OK button in the ActionBar (maybe something that looks like a tick-mark?) or must I create my own image file?

Comment: Take a look at [Done + Discard](https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/R49wVvcDoEW).

Answer (score 0):

I found this icon in Sherlock, it looks like a tick mark and it seems to do the job:

```
abs__ic_cab_done_holo_light.png
```

So this is my menu xml (located in res/menu):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item
      android:id="@+id/done_item"
      android:icon="@drawable/abs__ic_cab_done_holo_light"
      android:showAsAction="always"
      android:orderInCategory="1"
      android:title="@string/done">
   </item>
</menu>
```